# Automate matching a year and then cut and paste

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a way to automate checking a cell (in this case a year i.e. 2008 to 2013) and when a match is made execute a cut and paste, essentially sorting the data found in a range of cells (just to the right of the year) into columns? further along in the same row.

[image: SO18738548 question example]

**Edit**

Ok Team I seem to have figured out how to do it manually, see an abbreviated portion of code

```
If ActiveCell = 2013 Then
ActiveCell.Offset(, 2).Range("A1:E1").Select
Selection.Cut
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll ToRight:=24
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 24).Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
End If

If ActiveCell = 2012 Then
ActiveCell.Offset(, 2).Range("A1:E1").Select
Selection.Cut
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll ToRight:=18
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 18).Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
End If
```

Now how to automate?

Second Edit...

Ok team I have solved the problem with the following code, thanks to the guys here in pointing me in the right direction....  great job...

```
Option Explicit

Sub NoTears()

Dim c As Range
Dim lastrow As Long

lastrow = Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For Each c In Range("F1:C" & lastrow)

 Select Case c.Value

 'Case Is = 2009
 '   c.Offset(0, 2).Resize(1, 5).Cut Cells(Rows.Count, "??") _
       .End(xlUp).Offset(1)

Case Is = 2010
    c.Offset(, 2).Range("A1:E1").Select
    Selection.Cut
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll ToRight:=8
    c.Offset(0, 8).Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

Case Is = 2011
    c.Offset(, 2).Range("A1:E1").Select
    Selection.Cut
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll ToRight:=14
    c.Offset(0, 14).Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

Case Is = 2012
    c.Offset(, 2).Range("A1:E1").Select
    Selection.Cut
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll ToRight:=20
    c.Offset(0, 20).Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

Case Is = 2013
    c.Offset(, 2).Range("A1:E1").Select
    Selection.Cut
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll ToRight:=26
    c.Offset(0, 26).Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

  End Select
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I take it that is the community response for look a little harder perhaps?

Comment: Fair enough... Ok I have done the macro recording, and essentially the task was completed by hand (tedious when we are considering thousands upon thousands of rows).  I have created essentially 4 macros, which shortcut the 'cut and paste' in the correct columns.  The problem is each row still needs to be interrogated manually and then the correct macro executed.  This has cut the actual time down to about 50% of previous, however I am stuck at the 'how to completely automate the problem.  I am guessing it is inserting a If  - Then statement somewhere in the macro...

Comment: Why not use Excel built-in sorting?

Comment: Yeah at this stage there would have to be a fifth macro, checking the condition of the 'year' column.  The fifth macro would then call whichever macro was appropriate (the macros I have already created).  What I have a problem is how to code the fifth macro to conditionally check each date in the year column (i am guessing they would become the 'active.cell' and then keeping everything aligned during the 'cut paste' run of the macro...

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

**Not Tested**

```
Dim Cell As Range
Dim lastRow as Long

lastRow = Range("F:F").Find("*", Range("F4"), searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row 'this finds the last row in column F that contains data

For Each Cell In Range("F4:F" & lastrow) 'Loop through the whole table
    Select Case Cell
        Case 2008 'If the cell contains 2008 then...
            lastRow = Range("AD:AD").Find("*", Range("AD4"),searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row 'Find the last used row in your new table
            Range(Cells(Cell.Row,8),Cells(Cell.Row,12).Copy Cells(lastRow + 1,30) 'Copy/paste the data into your new table
        Case 2009
            'Same concept as before
    End Select
Next Cell
```

**Not Tested**

You will need to modify this to suit your needs. Specifically you'll need to update the column and offset numbers to match your data and tables correctly (I tried my best guess but I could be off).